# Cant call on list object when generating from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
import random

avchars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
ra = random.randint(8,24)
rb = random.randint(1,7)
for i in range(ra):
  file = open("pass","w")
  ac = avchars(rb)
  print(ac)
  file.write(ac)
file.close()
print("Done")
```

I want to generate 8-24 characters from the list above. However, I receive the error:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Should be `avchars[rb]`, not `avchars(rb)`.

Comment: that returns `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Of course, what do you expect? Indices start at `0`. So `rb = random.randint(0,6)`.

Comment: thanks, also is there anyway of making the output come out all in one line on the file

Comment: It doesnt really that much

Comment: but i would greatly apreiciate if you could explain to me how to do that.

Comment: Also, ive edited the file format to txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter version:

```
with open('pass', 'w') as fobj:
    fobj.write(''.join(random.choice('abcedfg') for _ in 
                       range(random.randint(8, 24))))
```

The used functions:

> ```
> random.choice(seq)
> ```
>
> Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence.

and

> ```
> random.randint(a, b)
> ```
>
> Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.

Comment: thankyou that worked <3. Im thirteen atm and my teacher has given me a exam for 4 years above me cause he thinks i can do it(for practice). I dont know how to do it at all. This has really helped. thanks

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A list is not a tuple or sequence. Therefore you cannot use:

```
avchars(rc)
```

instead use:

```
avchars[rc]
```

then your code will not throw an error.